# I changed "proof" to "solution" in environment but it's not updating? I think it has to do with babel?

Tags: formatting, csquotes, proof-package, quotation

```
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\addto\english{\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Solution}}
```

I successfully change my double quotes but unfortunately, "Proof" comes up but not "Solution." Can someone please help me? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\author{}
\date{September 18, 2020}
\title{\textbf{Homework 1}}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}


\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{marginnote} %can use \marginpar{}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %colors by name
\usepackage{soul} %strikeout using \st{}


\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[theorem]{Definition}

\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 |}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{| #1 \rangle}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.25ex}


\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\addto\english{\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Solution}}
```

Comment: Welcome! How are you producing the text that should read “Solution” instead of ”Proof”?

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I'm using TeX for the first time today for a problem set. Anyway, I did \renewcommand*{\proofname}{Solution} and I successfully changed "Proof" to "Solution." However, when I added the first three lines of commands in my post that involve changing the outer quote, "Solution" changed back to "Proof." I then tried \addto\english{\renewcommand*{\proofname}{Solution}} but it didn't work.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: `\addto\captionsenglish` might be more sensible in the last line

Comment: @egreg it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The list to act on is called `\captionsenglish`:

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\proofname}{Solution}}
```

will do.

Answer (score 1):

With a recent version of `babel` (>3.51, 2020-10-27), the best option is:

```
\setlocalecaption{english}{proof}{Solution}
```